# What is the difference between the research area of "ad hoc networks" and "device-to-device communication"?

Tags: terminology

I wonder what "device-to-device communication" (from a research perspective) covers what "ad hoc networks" don't.

To the context of this question: I am reviewing papers which deal with "device-to-device communication" (D2D). And all aspects of the presented approaches are known to me from the research field of "ad hoc networks" (which started emerging 20 years ago). Obviously, I was searching for the background information and Wikipedia and Google only confirmed the similarities between both fields. Hence, my question is what are the differences between both (research fields)? And I would mostly be interested from the point of view of research questions, since I am aware that technologies changed in the last 20 years.

http://www.comsoc.org/wirelessmag/cfp/device-device-d2d-communications-social-awareness
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network

Comment: @D.W.  Could I address your concerns?

Comment: Much improved, thank you for the additional context!  That looks very helpful.  Hope you get a useful answer.